# WINDOWS authentication in siingle sign on

Tags: windows, authentication, ldap

I have a website that was hosted by IIS to intranet. I want access the username of the each user who is accessing the website in intranet by using single sign on method. How can I achieve it?

I am using asp.net and c# languages in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity. You can cast Identity as WindowsIdentity to retrieve some more user information.